# Error with Python Cursor

Tags: python, sql

I write a script that inserts in DB directly with the python cursor object

```
 cursor.execute("INSERT INTO info ([height], [weight],[type]) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)" % (height, manufacturerid, weight))
```

Sometimes I don't have a number for "weight" and it throws an error:

```
Incorrect syntax near ','. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

How you handle errors like this?

Answer (score 1):

According with the docs, you should never do the query like this (the way you have):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO info ([height], [weight],[type]) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)" % (height, manufacturerid, weight))
```

You should do it as follows:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO info ([height], [weight],[type]) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)" , (height, manufacturerid, weight))
```

Check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

With try, except see the python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT be using string formatting for sql queries.  Let that get handled at a layer more apt:

Instead of:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO info ([height], [weight], [type]) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)" %(height, manufacturerid, weight))
```

Use

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO info ([height], [weight], [type]) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (height, manufacturerid, weight))
```

will likely fix your problem, and not be subject to sql injection or problems like the one you are having.

Since this seems to be Oracle, and I have not used it with Python, refer to the docs, but PEP 249 states that the placeholders for parameterized queries are:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle